# How to randomize the first letters of your first, and last name

Tags: python, function

For my homework I am supposed to create a program that takes the first name and last name from user input and randomizes the first letter of each name given. I've gone through all my notes looking for something that can do this, but unable to find it.

Example :

`"First, please enter your first name: Nikki`

`Now, please enter your last name: Manuel`

`I'm going to switch the letters of your first and last name to give you a funny name! Your new name is....... Mikki Nanuel HAHA! Isn't that hilarious?"`

```
 print('Option 3! lets switch up them letters!')
            f_name = input(str("Input your First Name: "))
            l_name = input(str("Input your Last Name: "))
            print()
            print(f_name [0:1],  l_name [0:1]) # This is just me trying to use anything. 
            print()
            print('Thanks for using my program!')
```

This is what I have so far

Comment: this should give you an idea on how strings work in python: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/string-manipulation-in-python

Comment: That is NOT "randomizing" in any sense of the word.  If you know that `xxx[0]` is the first letter of the string and `xxx[1:]` is the rest, then the solution should be easy.

Answer (score 2):

This code works:

```
import random

letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
name = input("Input your name: ")
random_letter = letters[random.randint(0, len(letters)-1)]
new_name = random_letter + name[1:len(name)]
print(new_name)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import *
print('Option 3! lets switch up them letters!')
f_name = input(str("Input your First Name: "))
l_name = input(str("Input your Last Name: "))

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
           'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

first_letter = randrange(1, 27)
second_letter = randrange(1, 27)

f_name[0] = letters[first_letter]
l_name[0] = letter[second_letter]

print(
    f"I'm going to switch the letters of your first and last name to give you a 
funny name! Your new name is: {f_name} {l_name}.")
print('Thanks for using my program!')
```

here is what you need.